# WP post meta - for loop inside for loop

Tags: php, custom-field, wp-admin, post-meta, array

I wanna make a portfolio on-click opening images gallery using meta fields.
So firstly I make array of portfolio images and loop them. Then I loop gallery images of every portfolio item, but it loops the same data, it's look like not saving properly. How to save properly so that every portfolio item will have own gallery images? Any help will be appreciated

Here my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $portfolio_item_no; $i++ ){
    $html = "<img id='m_img_preview_m_img_$i' src='"  .$pi_main_img[$i] . "' alt='" . $pi_main_img_alt[$i] . "' />
    <input type='number' name='pi_slide_no[]' id='slideNo-$i' class='form-control' value='" . $pi_slide_no[$i] . "' />";

    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $pi_slide_no[$i]; $i2++ ){
        $html .= "<img id='slide_m_img_sld-$i-$i2' src='" . $pi_slide_img_link[$i2] . "' />
         <input type='hidden' id='slide_link_m_img_sld-$i-$i2' name='pi_slide_img_link[]' value='" . $pi_slide_img_link[$i2] . "' />";
    }
}

// To call
$pi_main_img = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_pim_main_img2", true);
$pi_main_img = ($pi_main_img != '') ? json_decode($pi_main_img) : array();
// ...

// To save
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['pi_main_img'] ) ) {
$pi_main_img = (isset($_POST['pi_main_img']) ? $_POST['pi_main_img'] : '');
$pi_main_img = strip_tags(json_encode($pi_main_img, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
update_post_meta($post_id, "_pim_main_img2", $pi_main_img); 
}

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['pi_slide_img_link'] ) ) {
$pi_slide_img_link = (isset($_POST['pi_slide_img_link']) ? $_POST['pi_slide_img_link'] : '');
$pi_slide_img_link = strip_tags(json_encode($pi_slide_img_link, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
update_post_meta($post_id, "_pim_slide_img_link2", $pi_slide_img_link); 
}
```

Comment: first thing that bugs me, is that you create a new variable `$counterXC & $slideNo` while you have `$i & $i2`. what happens, when you replace `$counterXC & $slideNo` with your `$i`s and get rid of the `$counterXC++ & $slideNo++` completely..?

Comment: @honks31 ok, then? :)

Comment: so what are you doing with `$html`? the way i see it, you overwrite it with each iteration of your first `for` loop and than you do nothing with it..? maybe place `$html = ''`in front of everything and than in the first `for` loop replace `$html =` with `$html .=`..?

Comment: @honk31 its already displaying content, outer loop works ok, but inner loop saves one data for all, it loop same object every time. Problem with saving inner loop items

Comment: @honk31 any idea?

Comment: inner loop means your for loop inside the for loop? well yeah, they run the same thing in the end. `$pi_slide_img_link` is an array and it is called with the same keys `$i2` as in every run. each run starts with 0..